# Capturing password typed in webpage - HTML replace

Tags: man-in-the-middle, keyloggers, sniffing

For a while I've been documenting some exploits (I was afraid about man-in-the-middle) and an idea came into my mind.

When a user makes a request to a server, the browser might try to use http because the server might not support by default https.

However, this request is sent on LAN, so every PC can see it (maybe with a sniffer). However, if my computer could quickly respond to the request, maybe with the right header indicating that the request is genuine, then the browser would display my webpage (and leave it on HTTP not HTTPS).

Now if the user requested `google.com/login`, then I could provide a webpage with this page loaded in an iframe and some keyboard event in my JS (although Google cannot be loaded in an iframe). This is basically a keylogger.

Can't this be done? It would look like a deformed man-in-the-middle attack. If it's possible, why aren't there people exploiting this? (I never heard about this attack anywhere).

Comment: request aren't made "to a webpage", but to a server. And what you claim makes no sense – no information is sent before an encrypted channel has been established, especially not the URL asked for. And by specifiying a HTTPS URL, you instruct the browser to **not** accept someone man-in-the middling.

Comment: I didn't claim anything. I edited the answear(it was "FOR" a webpage). And when the user types "google.ro" the browser sends the request and waits for data.That data should be unecrypted because it will contain the public key for encryption.And I still have to see someone typing "https" in the url bar.

Comment: @Marcus..I found some documentation for you: http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/  You may read it.

Comment: That's not how transport layer security works, at all, sorry.

Comment: You connect to a server, and establish a TLS channel, before the first byte of HTTP traffic is ever transmitted. And you're definitely not referring to URLs typed in the address bar (then your question would make even much less sense, since you could fake the whole page), but about information sent via forms to HTTPS servers. The page that contains the form define's the form's target url, and that will include the info whether HTTPS or not.

Comment: and that blog post you linked to describes exactly what I'm saying. By the way, there's a difference between documentaiton of a standard (like HTTPS/TLS) and a blog post.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is possible.

I analyzed the packets being sent by my computer (with Wireshark) and I found the redirection header received back from google. From http to a https one. I  even found out that I don't need to "take over" the connection by quickly responding (I thought that would stop the browser that made the request to receive or interpret the real packet because it would have already taken its data from my http packet)  because there are already available exploits like ARP Spoofing that makes sure I get EVERY packet I want with no "collisions".

Because I know the user wants to access google, and I can't possibly allow the user to connect to it over ssl, I will be the one to make a secure connection with the host. I will receive everything as plain text over ssl (because I just read the packet received from google) and then on a not-secured connection I send the html data to the client that requested it (I make sure it doesn't get the redirect packet so it will think the server normally responded over http).

The way it works: user makes a request over http and sends it to me, I encrypt the request and send it over like https to google. I receive response, I decrypt and send the plain response to the victim over http.

For more information about this exploit I found out this website http://techgenix.com/understanding-man-in-the-middle-attacks-arp-part4/amp/

Comment: From what I can see, you're saying that if a request on a lan is made to an HTTP site, and you've MitMed the connection, you can prevent the connection from being upgraded to HTTPS?

Comment: It's worth noting that "However, this request is sent on LAN, so every PC can see it (maybe with a sniffer)" is only true if the LAN is a wireless or non-routed LAN. Routers don't broadcast connection requests to the entire LAN, so unless you have access to a network device in the direct path of the traffic, you won't be sniffing anything.

Comment: It might be difficult to understand, but your proposed answer, in fact, does not satisfy your requirements in your question. To ARP spoof, you end up directly in the middle of the connection, not beside it. Once you are ARP spoofing, then any form of redirection or manipulation of the stream is possible. That means, your proposed solution is not innovative at all, but comes standard in Ettercap. MITM is the only way this will work.

Comment: If you wanted to *respond* to seeing a client send a request to Google by initiating an ARP Spoof attack so that you could step in the middle, there are technical realities that make this infeasible. You and the server are effectively seeing the request at the same time. By the time the ARP spoofing was successful, the server will have responded. Your ARP attack would have to be faster than the returning request and the attack has more things to accomplish. It's a race that the attacker is unlikely to win.

Comment: @schroende Read the answer. You really make no sense. When did I say I would initialise ARP spoofing after the request packet was sent? " even found out that I don't need to "take over" the connection by quickly responding (I thought that would stop the browser that made the request to receive or interpret the real packet because it would have already taken its data from my http packet) because there are already available exploits like ARP Spoofing"

Comment: I thought if I could respond to the http request over tcp than the browser would ignore the real TCP packet because it would have been a dublicate(I said maybe). BUT(you do know what but means ,right?) I found this nice program that redirects ALL traffic to my computer so ....Who said I would initialise an attack immediately after detecting the user sent a request to google server? Why on earth would I do that? As you said..I can't even see the  request made without that "spoofing"...Read again your comment and my answer.

Comment: @sergiureznicencu I seriously thought about your *question* and devised a way where it *might actually work*. You have missed that point. If you didn't want to ARP spoof constantly (that would be noticeable), I thought about a way that might work, which was by reacting to the request. If you read my comment, you will notice that I said that it was *infeasible* not *impossible*. Why would you be so rude to someone (a 20 year professional and moderator here) *when he actually proved your entire premise*? But I see you just want to pick fights.

Comment: By the way, you can't say "it is possible" and then completely avoid the constraints in your question followed by comments saying that it is not possible. Your answer doesn't answer your question, it just comes up with a whole new scenario. That's why it is getting downvoted. That plus your overly rude comments when you just proved everyone's points.

Comment: Sorry for my tone. But imagine how I feel after my answer was downvoted by someone who tried to correct me that I confused the user for a browser(a human being with a computer! -"The user does not make a request to the server, the browser does"). I commented on your answer. I appreciate it. It was the only one logical. I looked more into NIC and how Wireshark actually works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your an moderator can you then delete this question? I can't do it now...and I don't want other people that have the same ideea see the ...answers.

Answer (score 0):

> When an user makes a request to a server, the browser has no idea it's going to be encypted (the connection hasn't been extablished yet - in the first miliseconds at least).

The user does not make a request to the server, the browser does. The user at most asks the browser to connect to a specific site by clicking on a link or by explicitly entering a URL into the status bar. Only in the second case it can be that there is no explicit protocol specification given by the user (i.e. `www.example.com` instead of `https://www.example.com`) so that the browser has to guess if the user means `http://..` or `https://..`. In this case it will assume insecure `http://..` unless it already knows better that `https://..` should be used instead. The browser might have this knowledge from earlier connection where there was a permanent redirect to HTTPS or a [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header within an earlier response from the target site which specified that in the future only HTTPS should be used. Or the browser might come with preloaded HSTS information in which case no earlier visit to the specific site is needed. For example Firefox and Chrome come with preloaded HSTS for some essential sites like google.com.

Thus in all cases it is known from the URL before connecting if HTTP or HTTPS should be used. The only problem is if the user has entered a partial URL (without protocol specification) that the browser has no knowledge of the target site yet and thus might have guessed the intention of the user wrong by choosing HTTP instead of HTTPS. Thus the browser might have the wrong idea which protocol to use but it is wrong to say that the browser has no idea at all which protocol to use. And if HTTPS is used an attacker in the local network could not simply reply with some bogus data as you imagine unless the attacker has a valid certificate for the target site issued by a trusted CA. This is how TLS works.

Comment: @sergiureznicencu: see updated answer.

Comment: Well now it makes sense. I was thinking the browser could retain some data. But except for this knowldge the attack could be possible right? And do you have some doc for tls? Because I still can't imagine how can tls be made without an attacker exploiting this.

Comment: @sergiureznicencu: The doc for TLS is the [RFC5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) but I'm not sure how this will help you. I also don't understand what kind of data the browser should retain in your opinion and how this would help with the decision of using HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: It is a misunderstanding. When I said "browser could retain.." I was refering to your post "The browser might have this knowledge from earlier connection ". And why everyone takes the question literally? "The user does not make a request to the server, the browser does". Instead of answering you "block" yourself in non-sense. "No, the user triggered the action that made the browser send the request.It is the user that actually requested the page or <<demanded>> the browser to..." I could say. It leads to nowhere.I was only asking if the "attack" is possible.

Comment: @sergiureznicencu: I'm not sure if blaming others for your confusing question (comments indicate that they don't really understand what you mean too) is a good idea if you want help with your question.

Comment: "And if HTTPS is used an attacker in the local network could not simply reply with some bogus data as you imagine". No I didn't even imagined such a thing if you read (here we go again) the question.My scenario only worked when the browser ,with no prior information, tried to connect to a server using http(because it has "no ideea" that the server supports https-it might not).

Comment: I edited the question now. You pretend not understanding the question. In the second paragraph I said "the browser has no ideea that it should use https.." so it is clearly that I knew about who/how/when the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

> if my computer could quickly respond to the request, maybe with the
>   right header indicating that the request is genuine, then the browser
>   would display my webpage

How do you imagine this working? The browser makes a request to the server on a particular source port to a particular IP. If you send a packet to the client on that source port, the browser is not going to accept it because you are not coming from the correct IP. It's going to ignore this new, unrequested data stream.

In addition, firewalls will tend to block this kind of incoming traffic by default (no incoming connections, only responses on the same the IP/port/sequence stream).

In order for this to work, your machine *has to be the one to whom the request is made*, and that's where MITM comes in. If you are the 'gateway', then when the client sends a request to Google, it designates the Gateway (you) as the next hop, then, when you send data back, it will be interpreted by the client as a valid connection, and display what you send back. But, the ARP spoofing would have to be set up before the request was made (not after) because of the ARP protocol timings.

So, no, it is not possible the way you have set it up. Basic TCP/IP functions on the NIC, OS, and firewalls prevent this from happening.

Take a look at "stateful" vs "stateless" firewalls and what makes them look at 'states', for more info. When Marcus said "that is not how transport layer works", this is what he was talking about.

Comment: Yes,you're right. My scenario as stated is not possible. But in with ARP spoofing it' s possible(this is not anymore a question because it is a fact-there is an exploit for this). Look here http://techgenix.com/understanding-man-in-the-middle-attacks-arp-part4/amp/

Comment: I though I could intercept the traffic without the need of ARP spoofing because I was familiar to Wireshark which I don't believe uses any exploit to capture other packets(although I can use it to see other computer's traffic)

Comment: Actually on further research this is possible. It is called ip spoofing. There's no difference between this pc and another in terms of data except the ip. Everything can be spoofed. That's why a good sequence number on the tcp layer is very important.

Comment: The "speed" was important because I though that when I captured a packet I would only get a "clone" and the real one would still be sent (this still may happen if I only sniff on a cable without actually spoofing the connection). If I were to be the first one to respond then the ack number on tcp layer would change and the packet that would arrive from the real server would contain other sequence/ack and so the "victim" would refuse that packet (hopefully without closing the connection)

Comment: Ip spoofing will not work